# how to append items vertically python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this list :

```
List_of_all = [
        ['3', '0', '6', '5', '0', '8', '4', '0', '0'],
        ['5', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
        ['0', '8', '7', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '1'],
        ['0', '0', '3', '0', '1', '0', '0', '8', '0'],
        ['9', '0', '0', '8', '6', '3', '0', '0', '5'],
        ['0', '5', '0', '0', '9', '0', '6', '0', '0'],
        ['1', '3', '0', '0', '0', '0', '2', '5', '0'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '7', '4'],
        ['0', '0', '5', '2', '0', '6', '3', '0', '0']
        ]
```

And I need to also 9 vertically list of items 
My code :

```
vertical = []
x = []
n = 0
for List in List_of_all:
    for num in List[n]:
        x.append(num)
    vertical.append(x)
    x = []
    n += 1
    if n == 9:
        break
```

My out put :

```
[['3'], ['2'], ['7'], ['0'], ['6'], ['0'], ['2'], ['7'], ['0']]
```

Why this iteration dont't work true ?!
How should I define this to get

Comment: What is your problem? Your question seems to be a bit unclear. pleas explain it in more details.

Comment: i want 9 list from each list by items[0] to item[9] together up to down

Comment: google translator can sometimes be messed up :D

Comment: can you some expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List_of_all = [
        ['3', '0', '6', '5', '0', '8', '4', '0', '0'],
        ['5', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
        ['0', '8', '7', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '1'],
        ['0', '0', '3', '0', '1', '0', '0', '8', '0'],
        ['9', '0', '0', '8', '6', '3', '0', '0', '5'],
        ['0', '5', '0', '0', '9', '0', '6', '0', '0'],
        ['1', '3', '0', '0', '0', '0', '2', '5', '0'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '7', '4'],
        ['0', '0', '5', '2', '0', '6', '3', '0', '0']
        ]
vertical=[]
for i in range(9):
    print([x[i] for x in List_of_all])#for visual appeal only
    vertical.append([x[i] for x in List_of_all])
print()

for line_slicer in range(0,9,3):
    count=0
    for line in vertical:
        count+=1
        print(line[line_slicer:line_slicer+3])
        if count%3==0:
            print()
```

Output:

```
['3', '5', '0', '0', '9', '0', '1', '0', '0']
['0', '2', '8', '0', '0', '5', '3', '0', '0']
['6', '0', '7', '3', '0', '0', '0', '0', '5']
['5', '0', '0', '0', '8', '0', '0', '0', '2']
['0', '0', '0', '1', '6', '9', '0', '0', '0']
['8', '0', '0', '0', '3', '0', '0', '0', '6']
['4', '0', '0', '0', '0', '6', '2', '0', '3']
['0', '0', '3', '8', '0', '0', '5', '7', '0']
['0', '0', '1', '0', '5', '0', '0', '4', '0']

['3', '5', '0']
['0', '2', '8']
['6', '0', '7']

['5', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0']
['8', '0', '0']

['4', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '3']
['0', '0', '1']

['0', '9', '0']
['0', '0', '5']
['3', '0', '0']

['0', '8', '0']
['1', '6', '9']
['0', '3', '0']

['0', '0', '6']
['8', '0', '0']
['0', '5', '0']

['1', '0', '0']
['3', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '5']

['0', '0', '2']
['0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '6']

['2', '0', '3']
['5', '7', '0']
['0', '4', '0']
```

Comment: thank you Its the best way....and if i want to have 9 squares of this 3*3 what i have to do ???

Comment: @mujad I am not able to understand what you require. Can you give an expected output?

Comment: [3,5,0,0,2,8,6,0,7] and [0,9,0,0,0,5,3,0,0] and [1,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,5]

Answer (score 4):

Bold assumption: you are looking for the following transposition:

```
>>> list(map(list, zip(*List_of_all)))
[['3', '5', '0', '0', '9', '0', '1', '0', '0'], 
 ['0', '2', '8', '0', '0', '5', '3', '0', '0'], 
 ['6', '0', '7', '3', '0', '0', '0', '0', '5'], 
 ['5', '0', '0', '0', '8', '0', '0', '0', '2'], 
 ['0', '0', '0', '1', '6', '9', '0', '0', '0'], 
 ['8', '0', '0', '0', '3', '0', '0', '0', '6'], 
 ['4', '0', '0', '0', '0', '6', '2', '0', '3'], 
 ['0', '0', '3', '8', '0', '0', '5', '7', '0'], 
 ['0', '0', '1', '0', '5', '0', '0', '4', '0']]
```

The `zip(*...)` idiom is the simplest way to go about that in pure Python. Without the nested `list` casting, it will be an iterator over `tuples`.

Comment: Very clean way of transposing without importing modules, chapeau.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you are taking the diagonal array, you can do:

```
import numpy as np
vertical = np.diag(List_of_all)

print(vertical)
array(['3', '2', '7', '0', '6', '0', '2', '7', '0'], dtype='<U1')

# to put each element in a list do this
vertical = [[x] for x in np.diag(List_of_all)]

print(vertical)
[['3'], ['2'], ['7'], ['0'], ['6'], ['0'], ['2'], ['7'], ['0']]
```

Comment: [['3'], ['2'], ['7'], ['0'], ['6'], ['0'], ['2'], ['7'], ['0']] ..... Its not true item[0] of all lists together and list[1-9]

Comment: by item[0] of all list, you mean `[x[0] for x in List_of_all]` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of the first elements in all of your lists:

```
vertical=[i[0] for i in List_of_all]
```

this would be the same as

```
vertical= ['3','5','0','0','9','0','1','0','0']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the columns as folows:

```
from collections import defaultdict

List_of_all = [
        ['3', '0', '6', '5', '0', '8', '4', '0', '0'],
        ['5', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
        ['0', '8', '7', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '1'],
        ['0', '0', '3', '0', '1', '0', '0', '8', '0'],
        ['9', '0', '0', '8', '6', '3', '0', '0', '5'],
        ['0', '5', '0', '0', '9', '0', '6', '0', '0'],
        ['1', '3', '0', '0', '0', '0', '2', '5', '0'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '7', '4'],
        ['0', '0', '5', '2', '0', '6', '3', '0', '0']
        ]

if __name__ == '__main__':

    columns = defaultdict(list)

    for row in List_of_all:
        for j, item in enumerate(row):
            columns[j].append(item)

    print(columns[0]) # ['3', '5', '0', '0', '9', '0', '1', '0', '0']
```

Comment: Surly you can choose the answer that you like most.  but to be honest @schwobaseggl had given the most pythonic one.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you expect of output. If you want to get all the columns in the 2D list, one option is to use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> items = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
>>> items
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> columns = items.T
>>> columns
array([[1, 4, 7],
       [2, 5, 8],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

If you transpose the numpy array, the columns will be rows and vice versa.

Another way to do this is with numpy indexing:

```
>>> columns = [items[:, i] for i in range(len(items[0]))]
>>> columns
[array([1, 4, 7]), array([2, 5, 8]), array([3, 6, 9])]
>>>
```

If you simply want to use loops, you should iterate column-wise and not row-wise:

```
>>> columns = []
>>> for j in range(len(items[0])):
...     column = []
...     for i in range(len(items)):
...         column.append(items[i, j])
...     columns.append(column)
...
>>> columns
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

A more pythonic way for the latter solution would be with list comprehensions:

```
>>> [[items[i][j] for i in range(len(items))] for j in range(len(items[0]))]
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

That said, the solution provided by @schwobaseggl is a good way to do it too, very pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner stolen from [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/transpose-matrix-single-line-python/):

`t = [[m[j][i] for j in range(len(m))] for i in range(len(m[0]))]`